# HTML form's value adjustment triggered by radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, forms, http-post

I have a simple HTML form, which posts data to a php payment script.

Here it is:

```
<form method="post" action="">    
    <select name="os0" >
    <option value="">-- Pasirinkite produktą --</option>
    <option value="900">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 50 vnt. €7.22 EUR</option>
    <option value="700">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 100 vnt. €11.55 EUR</option>
    <option value="900">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 200 vnt. €20.22 EUR</option>
    <option value="1000">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 500 vnt €46.23 EUR</option>
    <option value="300">16oz/473 ml. Red party cups 50 vnt €8.08 EUR</option>
    <option value="1200">16oz/473 ml. Blue party cups 50 vnt €8.08 EUR</option>
    <option value="400">16oz/473 ml. Red party cups 100 vnt €13.29 EUR</option>
    <option value="200">16oz/473 ml. Blue party cups 100 vnt €13.29 EUR</option>
    <option value="3000">16oz/473 ml. Red party cups 200 vnt €23.11 EUR</option>
    <option value="100">16oz/473 ml. Blue party cups 200 vnt €23.11 EUR</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="delivery">Delivery?<br>

<input type="image" src="http://www.partycups.lt/images/uzsakyti.png" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I am really new to js, could someone assit me on writing a conditional sentence, that if the radio button is checked, it would add a static digit to a selected value from ?

If I wasn't very clear, please let me know, I will update the question! Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand `add a static digit to a selected value from`

Comment: A single radio button doesn't make sense, it can't be unchecked without resetting the form or using script based on another button. Either use two radio butons (e.g. yes/no) or one checkbox (e.g. checked is yes, unchecked is no). Also, why can't the server implement the logic based on whether the checkbox was checked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="delivery" type="radio" name="delivery" value="delivery">Delivery?<br>

if(document.getElementById('delivery').checked) {  
    //radio button is checked

  document.getElementsByName('os0')[0].value = "900";  // any static value
}
```

Comment: It should actually be `document.getElementsByName('os0')[0].value = "900";` since getElementsByName returns a NodeList of elements.